# Is there a way to set a string to specific value if the string is null?

Tags: c#

Given this:

```
var a = myString;
```

What I would like to do is to set the value of `a` to be "0.0.0" if the value of `myString` is null.

I know I can do this with some if check but is there a cleaner way to do this in the newer versions of C#?

Comment: `??` ..........

Comment: `var a = myString ?? "0.0.0";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`var a = myString ?? "0.0.0";`

In the end it's an if statement but written differently.

Comment: This is far from an `if statement` actually...

Comment: @Asunez If you think of C#, that you're right. But the machine is executing the same operations in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

var a = mystring ?? "0.0.0";

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to write many implementations:

```
var a = myString ?? "0.0.0";
var a = myString == null ? "0.0.0" : myString;
var a = myString is null ? "0.0.0" : myString;
var a = string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) ? "0.0.0" : myString;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check the value by a `IsNullOrEmpty()` method on `String` class, and by a `conditional operator` (?) like the following code you can set your own custom text whenever your string is null.

```
var a = !String.IsnullOrEmpty(myString) ? myString : "0.0.0";
```

Comment: Why "!" when you can swap the parameters between ":" - `var a = myString == null ? "0.0.0" : myString;`